# The following jquery did not run

Tags: closest

Jquery did not carry out!!!I don't know why

```
 $(".other-edithion").click(function(){ 
var city = $(this).closest('#city');
    if (city.is(":hidden"))city.fadeIn("slow");
    else {city.fadeOut("slow");}
 });
 $("#city").mouseleave(function(){
     $("#city").fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) if you have id of an element

```
var city = $('#city');
```

As jQuery.closest()

> Gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

If `#city` is not up through dom tree, selector will fail to match elements.

And for mouse leave,

```
$('#city, .other-edithion #city').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: In a header and footer page will use the same city id so in the footer here I want to differentiate

Comment: The other one is :if ($("#city").is(":hidden"))$("#city").fadeIn("slow");
  else {$("#city").fadeOut("slow");}
    });

Comment: $(".city_img").click(function(){ 
     if ($("#city").is(":hidden"))$("#city").fadeIn("slow");
  else {$("#city").fadeOut("slow");}
    });

Comment: Why would you do that? ids are meant to be unique. Anyways, then the problem is with your html structure and closest selector. If you could post the structure, maybe we could help

Comment: header: <div class="city_img"><img src="images/bt-diqu.gif"/></div><div id="city">content</div>                                          footer:<div class="other-edithion"><img src="images/bt-city.gif"/></div><div id="city">content</div>

Comment: As I quoted, up through dom tree means up. In footer, your #city is not up the dom tree, but next to it, so this should work $(this).next('#city');

Comment: The question now .$("#city").mouseleave() just in the header of city executed ,in the footer don't execution the $("#city").mouseleave ()

Comment: That is because of wrong usage, duplication of Ids of elements. You could work around it by using selector like $('#city, .other-edithion #city').mouseleave()

Comment: Is still wrong!!~~  You can see it: http://gospeltimes.cn/link.html      The top right click "Other areas" and the footer One

Comment: You can see it now ！Didn't change.

Comment: @user1458084 Stackoverflow is not the place someone will do all the researches for you. You should debug your code and find out problems by yourself. I mentioned all of problems you had and probable solutions, the rest is up to you :)